# Java JSSE SSLEngine cannot resume SSL session

Tags: java, ssl, jsse, sslengine

I am writing an application that uses SSLEngine with NIO, I writing both the client and the server.
The client is able to connect to the server and after he is connected i want him to be able to perform session resumption / renegotiation, but currently without luck..

As the code that uses the SSLEngine is pretty big (SSLEngine usage is SO complex!) i will write a simple pseudo code that demonstrate the situation:

```
Server:
    global sslcontext initialized once
    await new client
    client.sslEngine = create new server ssl engine using the global sslcontext
    client.handleHandshake and wait for it to be done
    handle client.

Client:
    global sslcontext initialized once
    sslEngine = create new client ssl engine using the global sslcontext
    performHandshake and wait for it to be done
    disconnect (close gracefully the connection)
    sslEngine = create new client ssl engine using the global sslcontext
    configure engine to not allow session creation
    performHandshake and wait for it to be done
```

** i am more then willing to post any part of the code that can help (even the full code although as i said it is huge..)

when i executing my program the first connection is successful but the second cause an exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No existing session to resume
```

did i miss some ingredient that is required for ssl session resumption?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SSLEngine will only resume sessions if you create it with [SSLContext.createEngine(host, port)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#createSSLEngine%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). Otherwise it has no way of knowing who it's talking to, so no way of knowing what `SSLSession` to join.

Comment: Thank you very very much - you just finished 3 days of endless googeling :)

Comment: @bennyl It's not documented, and it's not exactly obvious, but when you think about it it must be so ...

Comment: i dont think that it has to be that way - as the SSLEngine is separated from the transport layer, i thought that by using the same SSLContext to create 2 SSLEngines they will share the same SSLSession cache...

Comment: @bennyl The SSLEngine has only one way of knowing the target IP:port, and this is it. It doesn't see a SocketChannel or a Socket from early in the morning to late in the evening.

Answer (score 0):

SSLContext should be singleton.
You can use [netty 4.0.44.Final](http://netty.io/downloads.html) SslContextBuilder. Works resume session by sessionId.

```
private  SslContext sslContext;
...

if (serverSSLContext == null) {
    serverSSLContext = SslContextBuilder.forServer(new File("cert.crt"), new File("cert.key")).build();
}
channelPipeLine.addLast(serverSSLContext.newHandler(channelPipeLine.channel().alloc()));
```