# Using Spring Integration FTP to connect a FTP Server(vsftpd on ubuntu) that without config "require_ssl_reuse=NO"

Tags: spring-integration

As the title, if I config "require_ssl_reuse=NO" for vsftpd, the following configuration works well.

Is that possible and how to config Spring Integration FTP to connect the vsftpd that without config "require_ssl_reuse=NO"?

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/ftp/upload/test.txt.writing' while uploading the file; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to write to '/ftp/upload/test.txt.writing'. Server replied with: 522 SSL connection failed; session reuse required: see require_ssl_reuse option in vsftpd.conf man page
```

Here is my configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="ftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpsSessionFactory">
<beans:property name="host" value="202.101.1.106"/>
<beans:property name="port" value="21"/>
<beans:property name="username" value="tom"/>
<beans:property name="password" value="tom"/>
<beans:property name='clientMode' value='2'/>
<beans:property name='protocols' value='TLSv1, SSLv3'/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to FTPS server with data connection using same TLS session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398754/how-to-connect-to-ftps-server-with-data-connection-using-same-tls-session)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398754/how-to-connect-to-ftps-server-with-data-connection-using-same-tls-session) for work-around.

Subclass the session factory and override the `createClientInstance` method.

Feel free to open an 'improvement' [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and we can look at adding it as a feature to the framework. Even better, consider [contributing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc).

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your reply. But the constructor argument "isSharedSession" is for [DefaultSftpSessionFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/sftp/session/DefaultSftpSessionFactory.html), what I am using now is [DefaultFtpSessionFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/ftp/session/DefaultFtpSessionFactory.html).