# How to download file through ftp with tls authentication through spring integration

Tags: java, ssl, spring-integration, ftps

I am not able to download the file from ftp server when it is TLS authenticated. I have used the DefaultFtpsSessionFactory session for TLS authentication.EveryTIme polling is started "ERROR DURING HANDSHAKE OCCURS".

Although i am able to download file using FTPSClient of apache.common.net through normal java class.

my xml config is like :-

```
<bean id="ftpClientFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpsSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="52.172.153.35"/>
        <property name="port" value="21"/>
        <property name="username" value=""/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
        <property name="clientMode" value="2"/>
        <property name="bufferSize" value="100000"/>
```

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="plannedFtpChannel" 
        session-factory="ftpClientFactory" filename-pattern="*.xls" local-filter="plannedFilter" auto-startup="true"
        auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false" remote-directory="/planned" local-directory="/DataFiles/planned" >
        <int:poller fixed-delay="10000">
        </int:poller>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I am Getting error like :-

taskScheduler-6, received EOFException: error taskScheduler-6, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake %% Invalidated: [Session-4, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384] taskScheduler-6, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, description = handshake_failure

taskScheduler-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 160
Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 160
0000: D8 BE B6 80 50 63 4A A1   EA 00 DA A8 97 03 9D 39  ....PcJ........9
0010: 34 35 30 20 54 4C 53 20   73 65 73 73 69 6F 6E 20  450 TLS session 
0020: 6F 66 20 64 61 74 61 20   63 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69  of data connecti
0030: 6F 6E 20 68 61 73 20 6E   6F 74 20 72 65 73 75 6D  on has not resum
0040: 65 64 20 6F 72 20 74 68   65 20 73 65 73 73 69 6F  ed or the sessio
0050: 6E 20 64 6F 65 73 20 6E   6F 74 20 6D 61 74 63 68  n does not match
0060: 20 74 68 65 20 63 6F 6E   74 72 6F 6C 20 63 6F 6E   the control con
0070: 6E 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 0D   0A 4A BA 0F 0F 95 88 44  nection..J.....D
0080: 8E B4 90 D0 02 B1 1C DC   78 E1 76 C1 ED BA 2F 82  ........x.v.../.
0090: 3A 19 0B FA F2 09 61 6C   FB 06 06 06 06 06 06 06  :.....al........
taskScheduler-2, received EOFException: ignored
taskScheduler-2, called closeInternal(false)
taskScheduler-2, close invoked again; state = 5

Here Session reuse needs to be enabled as far as i have googled.
But,not able to do so!
Any suggestion.

Comment: As was commented on [your other question which you just deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676862/how-to-connect-through-ftp-with-tls-authentication-in-spring-integration-for-fil), see [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398754/how-to-connect-to-ftps-server-with-data-connection-using-same-tls-session).

Comment: am not able to configure it with xml  as it is suggested there.?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean. You need to create the customized session factory.

Comment: I have created the customised session factory and overriden the method createClientInstance(), but  still the same error persist;

Comment: Thanks for the input gary!
Here we have to override the getSession() and createClient() of DefaultFtpssessionFactory also for achieving the customised FTPSClient.!
Its working fine with this config. now!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to FTPS server with data connection using same TLS session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398754/how-to-connect-to-ftps-server-with-data-connection-using-same-tls-session)

Answer (score 0):

Here we have to override the getSession() and createClient() of DefaultFtpssessionFactory also for achieving the customised FTPSClient.! Its working fine with this config.