# FTPS Talend SSL Issue

Tags: ssl, talend, ftps, vsftpd

I get error when I want to upload file to FTP server with talend `TFTPPut` component.
This is the error:
 `SSL connection failed; session reuse required: see require_ssl_reuse option in vsftpd.conf man page`

Comment: have you tried to declare connection through a tFTPConnection, and then use this connection in your tFTPPut ?

Comment: If talend uses the apache commons-net library, this could be related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398754/how-to-connect-to-ftps-server-with-data-connection-using-same-tls-session