# SSL Session reuse in Apache FTPS client in JDK 8u161

Tags: java, ftp, ftps, apache-commons-net

Using Apache Commons-Net's `FTPSClient` to connect to a modern FTP/S server does not work. The reason is that they require SSL session reuse, i.e. the SSL session from the control connection needs to be re-used for the data connection.

This can usually be deactivated in the server, but that is

- insecure
- not always an option (since the server might not be under your control)

The correct solution would be to make the client actually re-use sessions. There is an [open bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NET-408) for Commons-Net but it does not look like that is going to be resolved any time soon.

Also, there is a "reflection hack" that was created by the authors of Cyberduck (an FTP client application) which is described [in their bugtracker](https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/5087) and, more in-depth, in a [blog post](http://eng.wealthfront.com/2016/06/10/connecting-to-an-ftps-server-with-ssl-session-reuse-in-java-7-and-8/). There is also a related [post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32404418/537738) describing this solution. They use reflection to access the internal cache of the JDK's `SSLSessionContext` and inject a new entry.

This hack worked fine until JDK 8u161 and 9.0.4 (?) where some changes to SSL were introduced that are described in the [changelog](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html). Apparently, some implementation details have changed causing the hack to not work any more.

As far as I can tell, there are the following options now:

- Stay on JDK 8u152 either until someone finds a solution/apache-commons-net gets patched/JDK changes get rolled back (not really an option, because that would cut off production systems from security updates)
- Use a different FTPS client (the only alternative I could find is proprietary and quite expensive)
- Try to reverse engineer the changes to the `SSLSessionContext` implementation to find a new workaround. Not only does this seem like a non-trivial task - a solution would likely be hacky again and is thus likely to break again any time.
- Do not use FTP/S any more

Can anyone suggest how to proceed here?

---

Related links:

- http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/security-dev/2016-December/015254.html
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170813
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NET-426

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as a duplicate; this question references the other question and explains how it no longer works in 8u161.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132702/537738).

Essentially, it is reverting changed behavior from JDK8u161 to the way this worked before. You need to set the system property

```
jdk.tls.useExtendedMasterSecret
```

to `false` to do that.

There are two ways:

- call `System.setProperty("jdk.tls.useExtendedMasterSecret", "false");` before initiating the FTP/S connection
- Pass the property to your java process with `java -Djdk.tls.useExtendedMasterSecret=false [...]`

Keep in mind that this solution disables a security enhancement JVM-wide - proceed with caution.