# Talend jobs when trying to connect in FTPS on Windows fails "module java.base does not "opens sun.security.ssl" to unnamed module"

Tags: java, ftp, window, talend, ftps

I've a Talend 7.3 job that create locally some .csv files and then send them to the FTPS server on 990 port. In the IDE all work, but when I export the job (right click -> build job) the .bat file give me this exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final sun.security.util.Cache sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionContextImpl.sessionHostPortCache accessible: module java.base does not "opens sun.security.ssl" to unnamed module
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:171)
        at org.talend.ftp.SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient._prepareDataSocket_(SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient.java:29)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._openDataConnection_(FTPSClient.java:628)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:785)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listNames(FTPClient.java:2905)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listNames(FTPClient.java:2956)
        at --------------.--------------_0_1.--------------.tFTPPut_1Process(--------------.java:14760)
        at --------------.--------------_0_1.--------------.runJobInTOS(--------------.java:15224)
        at --------------.--------------_0_1.--------------.main(--------------.java:14993)
Exception in component tFTPPut_1 (--------------)
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Received close_notify during handshake
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:129)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:356)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:303)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:250)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:202)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1501)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1466)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1048)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:297)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:178)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:329)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:396)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listNames(FTPClient.java:2916)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listNames(FTPClient.java:2956)
        at --------------.--------------_0_1.--------------.tFTPPut_1Process(--------------.java:14760)
        at --------------.--------------_0_1.--------------.runJobInTOS(--------------.java:15224)
        at --------------.--------------_0_1.--------------.main(--------------.java:14993)
```

I think the problem is something in Windows because I can't open a connection from terminal with `ftp open <host>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library/tool, you are using, seems to use this hack to allow connection to FTPS servers that require TLS session reuse:
[How to connect to FTPS server with data connection using same TLS session?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32398754/850848)

The hack requires reflection access. What does not seem to be allowed in your runtime. I'm not Java expert, but this question seems to cover the problem:
[How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41265266/850848)

*(Maybe someone with more Java experience can build upon this information)*