# How to connect to FTPS server with data connection using same TLS session from Apache Camel using custom FTPSClient?

Tags: ssl, apache-camel, ftps, apache-commons-net, camel-ftp

I would like to send files to FTPS server using Apache Camel. The problem is that this FTPS server requires that the TLS/SSL session is to be reused for the data connection. And I can't set `'TLSOptions NoSessionReuseRequired'` option for security reason to solve the issue.

As far as I know, Apache Camel uses Apache Common Net class `FTPSClient` internally to communicate to FTPS servers and Apache Common Net doesn't support this feature as described [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NET-408)

So I has implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398754/how-to-connect-to-ftps-server-with-data-connection-using-same-tls-session) workaround. Here is code of my custom `FTPSClient`:

```
public class SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient extends FTPSClient {

    // adapted from: https://trac.cyberduck.io/changeset/10760
    @Override
    protected void _prepareDataSocket_(final Socket socket) throws IOException {
        if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
            final SSLSession session = ((SSLSocket) _socket_).getSession();
            final SSLSessionContext context = session.getSessionContext();
            try {
                final Field sessionHostPortCache = context.getClass().getDeclaredField("sessionHostPortCache");
                sessionHostPortCache.setAccessible(true);
                final Object cache = sessionHostPortCache.get(context);
                final Method putMethod = cache.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("put", Object.class, Object.class);
                putMethod.setAccessible(true);
                // final Method getHostMethod = socket.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getHost");
                Method getHostMethod;
                try {
                    getHostMethod = socket.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getPeerHost");
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    getHostMethod = socket.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getHost");
                }
                getHostMethod.setAccessible(true);
                Object host = getHostMethod.invoke(socket);
                final String key = String.format("%s:%s", host, String.valueOf(socket.getPort()))
                        .toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
                putMethod.invoke(cache, key, session);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works brilliantly as standalone FTPS client in JDK 8 and JDK 11 as shown:

```
public class FTPSDemoClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        System.out.println("Java version is: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println("Java vendor is: " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));

        final SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient ftps = new SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient();
        System.setProperty("jdk.tls.useExtendedMasterSecret", "false");
        System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.enableSessionTicketExtension", "false");
        System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
        //System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
        
        ftps.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());
        ftps.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true));
        
        ftps.connect("my_ftps_server");
        System.out.println("Connected to server");
        
        ftps.login("user", "password");
        System.out.println("Loggeded to server");
        
        ftps.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        
        // Use passive mode as default because most of us are
        // behind firewalls these days.
        ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftps.setUseEPSVwithIPv4(true);

        // Set data channel protection to private
        ftps.execPROT("P");
        
         for (final String s : ftps.listNames("directory1/directory2")) {
                System.out.println(s);
          }
         
         // send file
         try (final InputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\testdata\\olympus2.jpg")) {
             ftps.storeFile("directory1/directory2/olympus2.jpg", input);
         }
         
         // receive file
         try (final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\testdata\\ddd.txt")) {
             ftps.retrieveFile(""directory1/directory2/ddd.txt", output);
         }
            
        ftps.logout();
        
        if (ftps.isConnected()) {
            try {
                ftps.disconnect();
            } catch (final IOException f) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am ready to use this custom `FTPSClient` in my Apache Camel route, first I create custom `FTPSClient` instance and make it available for Apache Camel:

```
 public final class MyFtpClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RouteBuilder routeBuilder = new MyFtpClientRouteBuilder();
        
        System.out.println("Java version is: " + System.getProperty("java.version")); 
        System.out.println("Java vendor is: " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));   
        System.setProperty("jdk.tls.useExtendedMasterSecret", "false");
        System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.enableSessionTicketExtension", String.valueOf(false));
        System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"); 
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"); 

        SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient ftps = new SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient();
        ftps.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager()); 
        // ftps.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true)); 
        ftps.setRemoteVerificationEnabled(false);
        ftps.setUseEPSVwithIPv4(true);    
        
        SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
        registry.bind("FTPClient", ftps);

        // tell Camel to use our SimpleRegistry
        CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);

        try {
            ctx.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
            ctx.start();
            Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
            ctx.stop();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in Apache Camel Route:

```
    public class MyFtpClientRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        // lets shutdown faster in case of in-flight messages stack up
        getContext().getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(10);
        
        from("ftps://my_ftps_server:21/directory1/directory2?username=user&password=RAW(password)"
                + "&localWorkDirectory=/tmp&autoCreate=false&passiveMode=true&binary=true&noop=true&resumeDownload=true"
                + "&bridgeErrorHandler=true&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&maximumReconnectAttempts=0&transferLoggingLevel=OFF"
                + "&readLock=changed&disconnect=true&ftpClient=#FTPClient") // #FTPClient
                        .to("file://c:/testdata?noop=true&readLock=changed")
                        .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");
            
        // use system out so it stand out
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("Use ctrl + c to stop this application.");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");
    }
}
```

And it works!
But, when I add another route in the same java code by adding second from clause like this:

```
from("ftps://my_ftps_server/directory1/directory2?username=user&password=RAW(password)"
                + "&localWorkDirectory=/tmp&autoCreate=false&passiveMode=true&binary=true&noop=true&resumeDownload=true"
                + "&bridgeErrorHandler=true&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&maximumReconnectAttempts=0&transferLoggingLevel=OFF"
                + "&readLock=changed&disconnect=true&ftpClient=#FTPClient") // #FTPClient
                        .to("file://c:/testdata?noop=true&readLock=changed")
                        .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");

from("file://c:/testdata?noop=true&readLock=changed&delay=30s")
                .to("ftps://my_ftps_server/directory1/directory2?username=user&password=RAW(password)"
                        + "&localWorkDirectory=/tmp&autoCreate=false&passiveMode=true&binary=true&noop=true&resumeDownload=true"
                        + "&bridgeErrorHandler=true&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&maximumReconnectAttempts=0&transferLoggingLevel=OFF"
                        + "&readLock=changed&disconnect=true&stepwise=false&ftpClient=#FTPClient") // changed from FTPClient to FTPClient1 
                .log("Upload file ${file:name} complete.");
```

it ruins my code, it throws exception:

```
    org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: null Socket is closed. Code: 226
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1155) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.setSoTimeout(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:637) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setSoTimeout(SSLSocketImpl.java:74) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP._connectAction_(FTP.java:426) ~[commons-net-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:668) ~[commons-net-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:658) ~[commons-net-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:221) ~[commons-net-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:254) ~[commons-net-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:212) ~[commons-net-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.doConnect(FtpOperations.java:125) ~[camel-ftp-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
```

Files, anyway are transferred to and from FTPS server by Apache Camel.

Interesting thing, when I don't share my custom `FTPSClient` and use one instance exactly for one route like this:

```
    SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient ftps = new SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient();
...
     SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient ftps1 = new SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient();
...
     SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
     registry.bind("FTPClient", ftps);
     registry.bind("FTPClient1", ftps1);

    from("ftps://my_ftps_server/directory1/directory2?username=user&password=RAW(password)"
                    + "&localWorkDirectory=/tmp&autoCreate=false&passiveMode=true&binary=true&noop=true&resumeDownload=true"
                    + "&bridgeErrorHandler=true&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&maximumReconnectAttempts=0&transferLoggingLevel=OFF"
                    + "&readLock=changed&disconnect=true&ftpClient=#FTPClient") // #FTPClient
                            .to("file://c:/testdata?noop=true&readLock=changed")
                            .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");
    
    from("file://c:/testdata?noop=true&readLock=changed&delay=30s")
                    .to("ftps://my_ftps_server/directory1/directory2?username=user&password=RAW(password)"
                            + "&localWorkDirectory=/tmp&autoCreate=false&passiveMode=true&binary=true&noop=true&resumeDownload=true"
                            + "&bridgeErrorHandler=true&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&maximumReconnectAttempts=0&transferLoggingLevel=OFF"
                            + "&readLock=changed&disconnect=true&stepwise=false&ftpClient=#FTPClient1") 
                    .log("Upload file ${file:name} complete.");
```

it works perfectly!

So, I have couple of questions:

1. Why does Apache Camel (I mean Apache Common Net) developers refuse (or can't) to add usage of same TLS session functionality to `FTPSClient` class since 2011?
2. Am I the only person who uses Apache Camel to work with FTPS server with data connection using same TLS session? I haven't managed to find solution anywhere.
3. Is it possible to force Apache Camel not to share custom `FTPSClient` instance what, I suppose is the root of the problem, but to create new instance of `FTPSClient` every time then route are processed? My solution doesn't seem elegant.
4. What is wrong in my custom `FTPSClient` implementation that leads to this error then I use instance of this class in Apache Camel? Standard `FTPClient` hasn't this issue, of course.

Comment: Does your (standalone-) client still work when you remove `System.setProperty("jdk.tls.useExtendedMasterSecret", "false");`?